# Changing Button Color On Click in MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, icommand

I have an `ICommand` that fires when a `Button` is pushed. I need to change the Background color of this `Button` when this happens. How can I do this using the MVVM pattern?

```
private DelegateCommand asioMuted;

public ICommand AsioMuted
{
    get
    {
        if (asioMuted == null)
        {
            asioMuted = new DelegateCommand(MuteAsio);
        }

        return asioMuted;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Mute" 
        Command="{Binding AsioMuted}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="29,282,0,0"  
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="42" 
        RenderTransformOrigin="-0.273,1.818" />
```

Comment: Is the color change to do with some logic in your ViewModel? Otherwise, why not let the view handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the button's background color to a brush property on your ViewModel.  Then, have the ICommand change the color of the brush on the view model.  Some might also suggest binding the color to an IsMuted property on the ViewModel and then using a converter to translate true/false to a brush.  This approach removes any UI specific details from the ViewModel.

Comment: Would I do this in the button's Code Behind?  I wasn't sure if this was best practice or not.

Comment: No.  In the same way that you've binded the button's command property to an ICommand on the view model, just create another property on the view model of type SolidColorBrush, for example, and bind that to the button's Background property. (you could use any kind of brush)

Answer (score 0):

@Quanta code-behind may contain UI logic code that implements visual behavior, so change the color of the brush on the viewModel  is against the mvvm pattern.

> The view defines and handles UI visual behavior, such as animations or
>   transitions that may be triggered from a state change in the view
>   model or via the user's interaction with the UI.
>   for support of my words: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx

Comment: I agree, and that's why I wrote the part about binding to an IsMuted property instead which adheres to MVVM.  Personally, I don't find much value in being that pure in my projects, so I thought I'd express both points of view.